# Can we use nested controller with react hook form

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, controller, radio-button, react-hook-form

I am trying to add a Controller inside a Controller. Is this allowed ?

I am getting a typescript lint error

```
'onChange' is already declared in the upper scope.
```

How can I fix the same ?  I have the scenario that I have a radio button to select if I want to watch movie or not. If the selection is to watch a movie I need to select which movie to watch from the list of selections displayed in autocomplete. I am able to achieve this without using form, but I want to achieve this using react hook form.

```
const isMovie = watch("isMovie", "WatchMovie");
```

```
<FormControl>
                <Controller
                  control={control}
                  id="isMovie"
                  name="isMovie"
                  defaultValue={isMovie.toString()}
                  render={({ onChange }) => (
                    <RadioGroup
                      onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                        onChange(value);
                      }}
                      defaultValue="Watch Movie"
                    >
                      <FormControlLabel
                        value="WatchMovie"
                        control={<Radio color="primary" size="small" />}
                        label="Select Movie to watch"
                      />
                      <Controller
                        control={control}
                        id="isMovie"
                        name="isMovie"
                        defaultValue={isMovie.toString()}
                        render={({ onChange }) => (
                          <Autocomplete
                            disablePortal
                            classes={{ root: classes.MuiFormControlLabel }}
                            options={(() => {
                              if (isMovie === "english")
                                return englishMovie;
                              if (isMovie === "Spanish")
                                return spanishMovie;
                            })()}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value.toString()}
                            renderInput={(params) => (
                              <TextField {...params} />
                            )}
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                              onChange(value);
                            }}
                           
                          />
                        )}
                      />
                      <FormControlLabel
                        value="donotwatchmovie"
                        control={<Radio color="primary" size="small" />}
                        label="Do Not watch a movie"
                      />
                    </RadioGroup>
                  )}
                />
              </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

change either function's name at upper Controller or under Controller into another

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  id="isMovie"
  name="isMovie"
  defaultValue={isMovie.toString()}
  render={({ onChange: onRadioChange }) => ( // <=== here to change name
    <RadioGroup
      onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
        onRadioChange(value);
      }}
      defaultValue="Watch Movie"
    >
    <Controller
      control={control}
      id="isMovie"
      name="isMovie"
      defaultValue={isMovie.toString()}
      render={({ onChange }) => ( // keep the original name, or reverse
        <Autocomplete
          disablePortal
          classes={{ root: classes.MuiFormControlLabel }}
          options={(() => {
            if (isMovie === "english")
              return englishMovie;
            if (isMovie === "Spanish")
              return spanishMovie;
          })()}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value.toString()}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} />
          )}
          onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
            onChange(value);
          }}
      />
    )}
  />
</RadioGroup>
```

)}
/>